# Drawing a VTK point in real-time

Tags: c#, vtk

I'd like to draw a point using the VTK library in real-time. I have a little problem while doing this, though. My program is drawing the point but I can't see it until I click on my windows control, the point represent the coordinated x of a magneto.

Here is my code:

```
 private void Pointdessinateur()
    {

        // Create the geometry of the points (the coordinate)
        vtkPoints points = vtkPoints.New();

        List<double> X = new List<double>(); // création de la liste
        List<double> Y = new List<double>();
        List<double> Z = new List<double>();
        // Create topology of the points (a vertex per point)
        vtkCellArray vertices = vtkCellArray.New();
        int i = 0;

        X.Add(XCnorm);
        Y.Add(YCnorm);
        Z.Add(ZCnorm);

        int[] ids = new int[X.Count];
        for (i = 0; i < X.Count; i++)
            ids[i] = points.InsertNextPoint(X[i], Y[i], Z[i]);

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)) * X.Count;
        IntPtr pIds = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(ids, 0, pIds, X.Count);
        vertices.InsertNextCell(X.Count, pIds);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pIds);

        // Create a polydata object
        vtkPolyData pointPoly = vtkPolyData.New();

        // Set the points and vertices we created as the geometry and topology of the polydata
        pointPoly.SetPoints(points);
        pointPoly.SetVerts(vertices);

        // Visualize
        vtkPolyDataMapper mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper.New();
        mapper.SetInput(pointPoly);
        vtkActor actor = vtkActor.New();
        actor.SetMapper(mapper);
        actor.GetProperty().SetPointSize(3);
        actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.25, 0.0, 0.0);
        vtkRenderWindow renderWindow = renderWindowControl1.RenderWindow;
        vtkRenderer renderer = renderWindow.GetRenderers().GetFirstRenderer();
        renderer.AddActor(actor); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve.

I just fogot to call the render on my `VTKRenderWindow`

```
renderWindow.Render();
```